# How to stop page reload ajax jquery in DJango

Tags: jquery, ajax, django-forms, django-views, ajaxform

So I wrote my first ajax jquery code in Django. It works fine. I am sending data through ajax format and goes successfully to view function and it creates what I really want to create. But the problem is that the page is being reloaded what I don't want to do. I want an alert message to show when data will be passed.

MY Form :

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="register">
     {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
      {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
                       <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                           <strong>Hello ap!</strong> {{ message }}
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                       </button>
                       </div>
            {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

    <hr>
      <label for="text"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="required"  required>
       <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label> <br>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="required" required > <br> <br>
      <label for="Password"><b>Password</b></label> <br>
      <input type="password"id="password" name="password"placeholder="required" required>
      <label for="ConfirmPassword"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="required" required>


    <hr>
    <button type="submit" onclick="register" id="btn-submit"  class="btn-submit">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container signin">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in</a>.</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

MY Ajax Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('register',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : 'register',
      data : {
           username : $('#username').val(),
           email    :$('#email').val(),
           password : $('#password').val(),
           password1: $('#password1').val(),
      },
      success:function(){
        alert("Created New User");
      }
    })
    })
    </script>
```

And my View function:

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password1 =request.POST['password1']

        if password == password1:
            if User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
                messages.warning(request,"username taken")
                return render(request,'accounts/register.html')
            elif User.objects.filter(email =email).exists():
                messages.warning(request,"email taken")
                return render(request,'accounts/register.html')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username = username, email = email, password = password)
                user.save()
                messages.success(request,"user created successfull")
                print("user created")
                return redirect('login')
                return HttpResponse('')
        else:
            messages.warning(request,"Password not matched")
            print(messages)
            return render(request,'accounts/register.html')

    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/register.html')
```

What I did wrong? What should I do now? Help Me Out, Good People.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // create user code
});
```

and remove `onclick="register"`.

You can use and submit form event (which is better for me, because, it binds the event to the form, but not click event to the button ):

```
 $("#register").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   //Code: Action (like ajax...)
 })
```